# Visualising WKT geometry string in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry, visualisation, well-known-text

Is there a simple tool in QGIS to graphically visualise geometry formatted as text?

*Example geometry:*

```
POLYGON((571178 6337246,571178 6402217,598061 6402217,598061 6337246,571178 6337246))
```

*Result:*

A layer in QGIS showing the polygon from above.

[image: result]

The intention is to do quick and dirty visualisation for debugging purposes - I feel it is easier to relate to a graphical representation than a coordinate list.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Try the "QuickWKT" Plugin (see the official page: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickWKT/).

[image]

Comment: @underdark, will QuickWKT render multiple WKT features in the same "paste"? That is, given your screenshot, can you input multiple features using some sort of delimiter? I tried comma, semicolon, and linebreaks but none of those worked. Any thoughts?

Comment: @elrobis You can add multiple geometries by splitting them with an linebreak, so that every geom is on a single line. No comma's or other delimiters needed.

Comment: Try  https://clydedacruz.github.io/osm-wkt/

Comment: It does not appear to be "experimental" anymore.

Answer (score 28):

Indeed there is! Look [here](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/qgis-delimited-text-layer-now-supports-wkt/) for how to achieve it with the *Add Delimited Text Layer* plugin.

Essentially you create a CSV file (although you should use a delimiter other than comma), where one column is the WKT representation of your geometry. Then when you select that file in the plugin, it picks up that there is a WKT column, and does the right thing.

I can't vouch for its robustness, but the sample you gave works fine:

```
id|wkt
1|POLYGON((571178 6337246,571178 6402217,598061 6402217,598061 6337246,571178 6337246))
```

[image]

Comment: In an ideal world, I would imagine a window with a textbox where I could input my string. But apart from my imagination, your solution comes close :) Thanks a lot, I will try it out.

Comment: An option would be to develop a plugin yourself, which would be a fairly simple bit of Python, or sponsor a developer to do it for you.

Comment: No need. QuickWKT already exists. We're approaching an ideal world ;)

Comment: In case anyone else didn't know how to change the delimiter, in Windows go to the control panel > Regional and Language Options > Additonal Settings/Customize > List Separator and type in | instead of ,

Answer (score 17):

## No Plugin required

In QGIS deploy a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

In the Query window simply paste the following expression:

```sql
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((571178 6337246,571178 6402217,598061 6402217,598061 6337246,571178 6337246))')
```

or with an [SRID code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system#Identifier)

```sql
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((571178 6337246,571178 6402217,598061 6402217,598061 6337246,571178 6337246))', 4326)
```

The result might look like this

[image: Result]

One can also achieve the same result by means of PyQGIS:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsProject

wkt_string = 'POLYGON((571178 6337246,571178 6402217,598061 6402217,598061 6337246,571178 6337246))'

layer = QgsVectorLayer(f"?query=SELECT ST_GeomFromText('{wkt_string}')", "result", "virtual")

if layer.isValid():
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

---

**References:**

- [PostGIS | ST_GeomFromText](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html)
- [Wikipedia | Well-known text representation of geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry)
- [Creating Virtual Layer programmatically in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227203/creating-virtual-layer-programmatically-in-qgis)

Answer (score 13):

In QGIS >=3.18.3 we can copy one or multiple WKT strings into clipboard and paste them using <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Paste Feature As</kbd> > <kbd>Temporary Scratch Layer...</kbd> into map canvas.
CRS needs to be adjusted afterwards.

Comment: Amazing approach. Quick and straightforward

Comment: This is far and away the best approach these days. So simple.

Comment: I was 30 minutes on different solutions to visualize the WKT - this is ingenious!

Answer (score 6):

Quick and dirty: select the record in the table of attributes, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and then paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> in a text editor. Along with attributes, you will also see the geometry as text.

Probably there are more elegant alternatives.

Comment: My goal is to visualise the string as geometry in a layer.

Comment: Even if this does not solve the question, it is still very useful! So thanks for the information!

Comment: It is not the answer that the author seeks, but it is as if you had given me that simple tool that you will always use. ¡¡¡ Thanks, thanks, very much !!!

Answer (score 0):

### Use a virtual field

1. Go to "Layer properties" > "Fields"
2. Activate edit mode
3. Open "Field calculator"
4. Add a virtual field, using the expression `geom_from_wkt($geometry)`

Done

Comment: The question asks to do it the other way round: They have a WKT from somewhere else and want do display the geometry in qgis.

Comment: @til_b oops! should read _from_ instead of _to_ ^^U

Comment: `geom_from_wkt` takes a wkt string as input, not `$geometry`, and you don't need to add a virtual field but replace the feature geometry (it's in the "available fields" dropdown) with the results of `geom_from_wkt`.