# Visualizing large number of WKT files in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a directory which stores the result of breaking up a big geometry into many parts. There are 100 files named `part-0000.wkt` to `part-0099.wkt`. I need to point QGIS to this directory and have it load and render all the wkt files. How can I do this? I read [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13270/visualising-wkt-geometry-string-in-qgis), but the QuickWKT plugin can't even load geometry from a file, much less a directory.

Also I am trying the add delimited layer tool and the OK button never gets enabled! What's up with that?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your options in the read delimited text dialog are such that it thinks the WKT is the header, and then there's no data, so it won't let you load. Untick the "first record has field names" and it should load. The dialog will look like this:

[image: delimited wkt]

Note that the WKT is now in a field called "field_1".

But how do you read 100 of these in at once?

As long as all your WKT files are exactly one line, then you can concatenate all the files into one WKT file and read them in one go.

On a Unix box, from the command line, its just `cat part*.wkt >all.wkt` - I think you can do something similar in Windows with COPY. Looking at your dialog box I suspect its a Mac, so you can use `cat` as for Linux.

Then in the delimited text layer dialog, select `all.wkt` and you should see the first few WKT strings in the dialog.

Comment: For Windows, consider this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16953785/1394393. I suspect there should be a `*` instead of a `?` in that pattern, though.