# Creating Virtual Layer with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, virtual-layer

Is it possible to create a Virtual Layer through a Python script?

For example, I have a layer `'road'`, and I would like to perform the SQL query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM road
WHERE type = 'Expressway'
```

Will this be possible? Is there any example I can refer to?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For QGIS 2 you could use something like the following:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsMapLayerRegistry

sql_query = "SELECT * FROM road WHERE type = 'Expressway'"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(f"?query={sql_query}", "vlayer", "virtual")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

You can find examples on how to use virtual layers through Python from the author's GitHub:

https://github.com/mhugo/qgis_vlayers/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I got an error in the Python console: `'QgsMapLayerRegistry' is not defined`. The SQL statement works when running in the 'Create a virtual layer' dialog.

Comment: Did you include the 'from qgis.core import ...' line? What version are you using?

Comment: @eclipsed_by_the_moon - Yes, you're correct. Edited the post to include the necessary imports (thanks to annoymous user for edit).

Comment: @Joseph Thanks for the link provided in your answer!

Comment: @CyT - Most welcome! Glad it worked =)

Answer (score 22):

For QGIS 3, instead use [`QgsProject`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProject.html):

```py
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsProject

sql_query = "SELECT * FROM road WHERE type = 'Expressway'"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(f"?query={sql_query}", "vlayer", "virtual")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

Comment: Given current LTR QGIS version is 3.10, this answer should be the new validated one !