# Creating virtual layers using the processing toolbox

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, virtual-layer

A few days ago Cy T posted an interesting question about creating virtual layers using the Python console:

[Creating new Virtual Layer programmatically in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227203/creating-new-virtual-layer-programmatically-in-qgis)

Is it also possible to create virtual layers through the processing toolbox?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# ----- define interface -----
##Virtual Layers=group
##Point on surface (ST_PointOnSurface)=name
##Input_polygons=vector

from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsMapLayerRegistry

inptlyr = processing.getObject(Input_polygons)

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer( "?query=SELECT rowid AS gid,ST_PointOnSurface(geometry)AS geom FROM inptlyr.name()", "vlayer", "virtual" )
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

The log says `Algorithm Point on surface (ST_PointOnSurface) finished`, but nothing happens.

Edit: `?query=` added

Comment: Maybe a `?query=` missing? I mean, does it change something using `?query=SELECT` ?

Comment: My fault, now QGIS crashes when running the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue lies with `inptlyr.name()`. Since you inserted it into the string, this is exactly how it will be read (and I doubt you have a layer called "inptlyr.name()").

Personally, I find it easier to separate queries/formulae as it makes it easier to find mistakes. So the following example works for me:

```
##Virtual Layers=group
##Point on surface (ST_PointOnSurface)=name
##Input_polygons=vector

from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsMapLayerRegistry

inptlyr = processing.getObject(Input_polygons)
query = """ SELECT * FROM '""" + inptlyr.name() + """' """

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer( "?query={}".format(query), "vlayer", "virtual" )
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

---

Two things to notice:

1. Single quotes are used for layer names (particularly useful when layer names contain spaces).
2. `inptlyr.name()` is ***outside*** the string so that the name can be extracted correctly.

So when the above query is read by the script, it will look like:

```
SELECT * FROM 'polygon example'
```

This should be enough to create and load your virtual layer. You can test it by using your query.

---

**EDIT:**

Your code could look like the following:

```
##Virtual Layers=group
##Point on surface (ST_PointOnSurface)=name
##Input_polygons=vector

from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsMapLayerRegistry

inptlyr = processing.getObject(Input_polygons)
query = """ SELECT rowid AS gid,ST_PointOnSurface(geometry)AS geom FROM '""" + inptlyr.name() + """' """

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer( "?query={}".format(query), "vlayer", "virtual" )
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```