# How to create a Virtual Layer using the QGIS Modeler?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, virtual-layer

At 3.28.4, I am trying to automate a series of manual steps using the Model Designer.

One of the manual steps that I would like to automate uses the **Layer > Create Layer > Create Virtual Layer** tool.  However, this tool does not seem available to the model environment, nor can I find an equivalent in the Processing Toolbox.

There's a [similar SEGIS post from 2017](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228021/creating-virtual-layers-using-the-processing-toolbox), but the answer required code, and I am not a programmer.

How can I create a Virtual Layer in my model?

**Edit:**

Matt's proposed answer - to use the *Execute SQL* tool - works with one exception: it **always** outputs a **point** layer (with EPSG 4326), even though:

1. My input is a non-spatial Geopackage table
2. I use either the *Not Selected, Autodetect,* or *No Geometry* Geometry types (screenshot below).

I need a non-spatial Geopackage table output.

(Maybe this should be a separate SE post regarding the Execute SQL tool???)

[image]

Comment: @Stu_Smith if create virtual layer is not available in the algorithms list of the modeler, I'm afraid that it is not (yet) possible to use virtual layers in models, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Add Drop geometries algorithm to the solution by @Matt : https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#drop-geometries

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the tool *Execute SQL*. It is not a Virtual Layer per se, but hopefully it allows you to do what you need.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Close! Execute SQL generates output, but please see my edit in the OP.