# Force virtual layer to based on layer's filter (query builder)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I have a layers, which are filtered by query builder.

Next I want to create virtual layer (VL), that is based on that filtered layers.
Sadly, I'm getting VL with all features from the layers. Query builder is ignored.

Is there a way to force VL to use an output from query builder, and not all features?

Comment: What about using the same query as an SQL command when creating your virtual layer?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that and it works just fine, but the problem is I need that original layer to be filtered. So I would have ended up with a duplicated query. I want to avoid that.

Comment: How are you creating a virtual layer? Could you [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/336744/edit) your post to include some code?

Comment: So far, I've been testing this through gui. The last step is to do that by code, but now I just want to figure out, what is possible, and what is not in virtual layer But I guess creating VL is quite the same as regular layers, eg. [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227203/creating-new-virtual-layer-programmatically-in-qgis)

Comment: What happens when you duplicate the layer with used filter and apply a VL over it?

Comment: I'm confused now. I've tried again and I don't know why, but it works somehow. It reflects each change I made to source layer. But why It didn't work earlier, no clue. I did what you suggested @Taras, but I use original layers (not duplicated ones) to apply VL over it. Don't know what helped, or I was doing something wrong...