# Creating virtual layers using Python and export them without using QGIS UI

Tags: pyqgis, virtual-layer, flow-map

I am trying to create a flow map and have 5000 nodes and millions of edges. I've used

```
SELECT StartID, DestID, Weight, 
       make_line(a.geometry, b.geometry)
FROM edges
JOIN nodes a ON edges.StartID = a.ID
JOIN nodes b ON edges.DestID = b.ID
WHERE a.ID != b.ID
```

which I found on https://anitagraser.com/2019/05/04/flow-maps-in-qgis-no-plugins-needed/.

Not surprisingly with known performance issues with virtual layers in QGIS, QGIS keeps crashing as it can't handle the large dataset.

I'm looking for ways I can create and export this using just python.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/357038/99589)? Another part of your question concerns the use of *'PyQGIS in standalone scripts'*

Comment: From a performance perspective, this still seems quite slow. Would an alternative workflow using shapely be faster?

Comment: IMHO, I would say yes. How many points do you have?

Comment: What is your **main** aim ? Doing it quickly or doing it programmatically ?

Comment: @Taras i have 5,500 nodes and 180 million edges.

Comment: @Snaileater I'd like to achieve both. It's something that I need to re-run every month so I'd like it to be done as efficiently as possible. The data also grows by 200MB every month.