# Unexpected behavior when creating Virtual layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, virtual-layer

I have already viewed this link and still having issues -
[Creating Virtual Layer with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227203/creating-virtual-layer-with-pyqgis).

When I create a virtual layer from the `Layer -> Add/edit virtual layer`  and use this as a query it works as expected, i.e. column 1 contains the subtype, and column 2 is the sum of lengths of each subtype

```sql
select "Subtype", sum(Length)
from 'roads'
group by "Subtype"
```

However, when I use the console and paste this, I only get one row where column 1 is just called a `"Subtype"` and column 2 has the total length of all subtypes. How can I get the same results using Python console script as I do when manually creating a virtual layer using the menu?

```py
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsProject

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("?query=select 'Subtype', sum(Length) from 'roads' group by 'Subtype'", "vlayer", "virtual")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to remove the single quotes, or use double quotes for field name instead.

```
"?query=select Subtype, sum(Length) from 'roads' group by Subtype"
```

or

```
"?query=select \"Subtype\", sum(Length) from 'roads' group by \"Subtype\""
```