# QGIS: Every input to QuickWKT results in a point at null island

Tags: qgis, well-known-text

If I open the QuickWKT plugin in QGIS, and choose "POINT (WKT)" from the combo box, and enter the text,

```
POINT (30 10)
```

I get a point at "null island" (0°N, 0°E). The entered WKT appears well-formed to me.

What's going wrong?

Note: [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/13290) includes a screenshot of QuickWKT. My QuickWKT does not look like that; it looks like this:

[image: my QuickWKT]

It isn't clear to me as a user why I need to specify `POLYGON` / `POINT` / etc. when the WKT itself encodes that. But the examples it has have those keywords, so I presume I'm supposed to enter them as well.

Answer (score 1):

POINT (30 10) is likely drawing at the correct spot - depending the your coordinate system of your QGIS map - if set to EPSG:4326 to see the point is not actually at 0,0... If your map is in EPSG:3857 you're putting a point in 30m and 10m from 0,0...

Zoom in really close and hover over the point, then check the 'coordinates' box in the bottom of QGIS... you'll see the point is not at 0,0 but its REALLY close to it.

As for the the distinction for geometry its likely in case someone doesn't have the  point/poly/line type in their WKT...

Comment: Thanks; this does seem to be my problem. It'd be nice if the WKT input allowed you to specify / told you up front what projection it was about to use. (Does anyone actually have data in "EPSG:3857"? All of my stuff is in lat/lng)
I'm able to get points to appear, but polygons are still hidden.

Comment: It might not be in 3857, but lots of people have stuff in metres - UTM, national grids / state planes, etc. Since you have an EWKT option, you can specify the SRS.

Comment: From the menu, choose `Settings -> Options`, `CRS` tab, `CRS for new layers`, and select `Prompt for CRS`. Then you can select the CRS every time when nothing is specified in the data. If you right-click on your point layer, you can adjust the CRS with `Set CRS for Layer`.