# Converting lines (edges) to polygons with Python

Tags: python, point, shapely, polygon-creation, plot

Is there any working function to convert lines (edges) to polygons with Python or I need to implement it myself?

I have pairs of points - edges:

```py
[[10464, 27071],
 [22358, 15839],
 [10464, 24781],
 [24781, 22358],
 [19888, 27071],
 [30361, 19784],
 [19784, 19888],
 [30361, 15839]]
```

which definitely are in a looping manner - they have their coordinates.

Placing them on paper a polygon is visible, because each point have some pair in the set, but couldn't find any algorithm to draw proper shape. This is not ambiguous. `Shapely` for example forces me to use convex or concave but I don't need to use it, because the shape is already determined with this lines. `Networkx` didn't solve topological order of neighboring nodes as well.

This code:

```py
poly = geometry.Polygon([[p[0], p[1]] for p in cxy])
x,y = poly.exterior.xy
plt.plot(x,y)
```

draws bad polygon (self-intersected) because the order of points is not right, but labels are straightly saying what it should be.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 11):

I will firstly start with your code. There is no need to manipulate the list with lists of coordinates, as you did it with `geometry.Polygon([[p[0], p[1]] for p in cxy])`. The class `Polygon(shell[, holes=None])` can accept it straight, as mentioned [in the documentation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#polygons):

> The Polygon constructor takes two positional parameters. The first is
> an ordered sequence of `(x, y[, z])` point tuples and is treated exactly
> as in the `LinearRing` case. The second is an optional unordered
> sequence of ring-like sequences specifying the interior boundaries or
> “holes” of the feature.

So, you can do the following:

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

list_with_coords = \
    [[10464, 27071],
    [22358, 15839],
    [10464, 24781],
    [24781, 22358],
    [19888, 27071],
    [30361, 19784],
    [19784, 19888],
    [30361, 15839]]

p = Polygon(list_with_coords)

print(p)
```

which results in:

```py
POLYGON ((10464 27071, 22358 15839, 10464 24781, 24781 22358, 19888 27071, 30361 19784, 19784 19888, 30361 15839, 10464 27071))
```

[image: result1]

---

Secondly to achieve the desired output, one can start with inspecting the [Alpha Shape Toolbox](https://github.com/bellockk/alphashape) package and considering one of these approaches.

### Approach 1 : [A Convex Hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)

> The convex hull, a shape resembling what you would see if you wrapped
> a rubber band around pegs at all the data points, is an alpha shape
> where the alpha parameter is equal to zero.

```py
import alphashape

list_with_coords = \
    [[10464, 27071],
    [22358, 15839],
    [10464, 24781],
    [24781, 22358],
    [19888, 27071],
    [30361, 19784],
    [19784, 19888],
    [30361, 15839]]

alpha_shape = alphashape.alphashape(list_with_coords, alpha=0)

print(alpha_shape)
```

which results in the :

```py
POLYGON ((22358 15839, 10464 24781, 10464 27071, 19888 27071, 30361 19784, 30361 15839, 22358 15839))
```

[image: result2]

### Approach 2 : [An Alpha shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape) a.k.a. A Concave Hull

Also as was mentioned by @gene to find an optimal Alpha Value

> The alpha parameter can be solved for if it is not provided as an
> argument, but with large datasets, this can take a long time to
> calculate.

```py
import alphashape

list_with_coords = \
    [[10464, 27071],
    [22358, 15839],
    [10464, 24781],
    [24781, 22358],
    [19888, 27071],
    [30361, 19784],
    [19784, 19888],
    [30361, 15839]]

alpha_shape = alphashape.alphashape(list_with_coords)

print(alpha_shape)
```

which results in:

```py
POLYGON ((10464 27071, 19888 27071, 24781 22358, 30361 19784, 30361 15839, 22358 15839, 19784 19888, 10464 24781, 10464 27071))
```

[image: result3]

---

**References:**

- [Real Python | Lists and Tuples in Python](https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/#python-tuples)
- [Creating single polygon from GPS coordinates and finding its area with Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/397986/creating-single-polygon-from-gps-coordinates-and-finding-its-area-with-python)

Comment: The result is always the bad polygon (self-intersected)

Comment: True, did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Yes, he wants the concave hull of the points ([Alpha shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape))

Comment: Your result is the simple convex hull of the points, you need to modify the alpha value to get a concave hull

Comment: True! With this parameter `alpha=0.5` currently getting this : ```C:\TempDaten\...\lib\site-packages\shapely\ops.py:42: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: Iteration over multi-part geometries is deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Use the geoms property to access the constituent parts of a multi-part geometry. source = iter(source) GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY``` issue

Comment: Use  `alphashape.alphashape(list_with_coords)` ('the alpha parameter can be solved for if it is not provided as an argument'    In [Pypi:alphashape](https://pypi.org/project/alphashape/) )

Comment: @Taras Generally your solution leads to right answer(s). But there's no need to treat it that way, because edges are just ready to bring together - just they need to be sorted like domino. With some help from other guy I found this is an Euler path. Resolved this with ` list(nx.eulerian_circuit(G))`` from `networkx` package. I was asking whether or not there's some package to just load these edges to be resolved automatically this way. It seems I guess, the concave solution makes the same thing.